# Trouble Generating Controllers for Rails in terminal: Open Flash Charts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, charts

Hi Folks thanks for your help here.
I am trying to create a rails controller in ubuntu terminal with "rails generate controller test_it"

But I keep getting a screwy error.  What does this mean?

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load': /tmp/rubygems-1.8.17/first_app/config/initializers/session_store.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end (SyntaxError)
...sion_store :cookie_store, key: '_first_app_session'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is probably caused by running in Ruby 1.8 rather than 1.9 (1.9 added support for a shorter syntax that's used in the session_store.rb file). Can you run it in Ruby 1.9 instead?